# Unable to read .xls file in python using xlrd

Tags: python

My Code -

```
import xlrd
xlrd.open_workbook('H:\DataSync\Projects\CV_Rec\Feed.xls')
```

Error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found 'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00'
File "D:\ATHENA~1\RELEAS~1\build\ext\noarch/pylib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1545, in getbof
File "D:\ATHENA~1\RELEAS~1\build\ext\noarch/pylib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1539, in bof_error
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I imagine that the XLS file is either in an unsupported format, or else it is corrupt.

Comment: What version of Excel did you use to create the file? I suspect it's an XML-format file, not a classic XLS file. xlrd only supports the older non-XML file format.

Comment: @kindall: It starts with `PK`, that's a ZIP file, thus most likely a zipped XML format (such as recent Office versions save). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Comment: Wild guess: the .XLS is obviously a ZIP and therefore should be named .XLSX. Perhaps xlrd is making assuptions about the parser to be used based on the suffix. .XLS is 100% not a ZIP-ish format.

Answer (score 1):

OK..I found the problem! The person from where I got this excel sheet had renamed the original file from 'Feed.xlsx' to 'Feed.xls'.

This is the reason for the corrupt file.